# Распарсить строку

Tags: preg_match, php

Добрый день.

Помогите распарсить строку.

```
ATR Sport 101 235/45R17C 97W
```

чтобы получилось

```
$a1 = ATR Sport 101;
$a2 = 235;
$a3 = 45;
$a4 = R17C;
$a5 = 97;
$a6 = W;
```

Answer (score 1):

Строка фиксированного формата?
Если да, то вот как-то так:

```
<?
$str = 'ATR Sport 101 235/45R17C 97W';
preg_match('!^\s*([a-z0-9\s]+)\s+(\d+)\/(\d+)([a-z\d]+)\s+(\d+)([a-z]+)\s*$!i', $str, $match);

$a1 = $match[1];
$a2 = $match[2];
$a3 = $match[3];
$a4 = $match[4];
$a5 = $match[5];
$a6 = $match[6];
```

Comment: <сарказм>Хороший ответ)))</сарказм>

Comment: почти, отличается только переменная $a1, она может без цифр..(т.е ATR Sport,ATR,Sport..)  и $a4 может быть без C

Comment: Сразу код не вставился, обновил.

@vasbkadg, эти отклонения допустимы, регулярка их обработает.

Comment: Спасибо тебе огромное)

Comment: Да без проблем.  
Отметь вопрос верным чтобы закрыть.